# Converting Biginteger to long causes error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, scala, playframework

I am moving a playframework app database from PostgreSQL to MySQL.

And I get this error when launching the app:

> Cannot convert 126: class java.math.BigInteger to Long for column ColumnName(Speaker.id,Some(id))

It seems to come from there:

```
def listAll: List[Speaker] = DB.withConnection {implicit c =>
SQL("SELECT * FROM Speaker;")
  .as(speakerParser *)}<---
```

Here is the code of the speackerParser:

```
private val speakerParser: RowParser[Speaker] = {
  get[Long]("id") ~
  get[String]("firstName") ~
  get[String]("lastName") ~
  get[String]("title") ~
  get[String]("team") ~
  get[String]("organisation") ~
  get[String]("email") map {
    case id ~ firstName ~ lastName ~ title ~ team ~ organisation ~ email => Speaker(id, firstName, lastName, title, team, organisation, email)
  }}
```

And the column wich cause my troubles is id:

```
Table: Speaker
Columns:
id  bigint(20) UN AI PK
title   varchar(20)
firstName   varchar(255)
lastName    varchar(255)
email   varchar(255)
team    varchar(255)
organisation    varchar(255)
```

This code is not from me but I need to modify it.

I am new to postgres, scala and Play so I may forget something really simple.

Comment: You're using some particular Scala database library - anorm, maybe?  Tell people what you're using, and tag with it.

Comment: Yes, I am using anorm library.
My Problem is resolved, I explained it in the commentar below.
I am new to StackOverflow, what do you think I should do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInteger can hold larger values than Int, so a conversion may or may not be possible without loss of information. If you can change the table definition to also use Int (or change both to Long) you can avoid the loss of information.

Comment: The original database in PostgreSQL was using SERIAL which was not the same as MySQL SERIAL, it corresponds more with a MySQL INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.
Thanks for the way you gived me to search.